# How can I use I2C to talk to sensors?

Tags: gpio, i2c

How can I talk to digital sensors over the I²C interface?

**Hardware:**
Which pins on the Raspberry Pi's GPIO can I use?

**Software:**
What I²C libraries are available?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's a lot of information about RPi's GPIO here: http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals

According to it, you can program any GPIO pins for I²C, but:

> Pin 3 (SDA0) and Pin 5 (SCL0) are preset to be used as an I²C interface. So there are 1.8 kilohm pulls up resistors on the board for these pins.

That wiki page also has some low-level GPIO code examples for various languages that should get you started. If you need a refresher on what I²C actually is, [here's one](http://quick2wire.com/articles/i2c-and-spi/) which also takes the RPi into account.

For specific I²C controlling, [this python library](https://github.com/quick2wire/quick2wire-python-api) might be helpful, it's discussed [in this blog post](http://quick2wire.com/2012/06/i2c-python/), which includes a code sample.

Comment: Any comments on potential for adapting Edison Sparkfun GPIO pins for I2C?

Answer (score 7):

Lots of discussions going on about this.  Here's what my reading and messing around with shows me:

1. I2C support is not built into the default kernel with the Debian "squeeze"
2. A custom kernel will have to be compiled with the i2cspi module ([Here is a GIT tree excerpt](https://github.com/selsinork/raspberry-pi-i2c-spi-drivers/blob/83ad8fecefc7a478cf2c059a89c828a791ca6711/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-bcm2708.c))
3. The drivers that have been written so far are only for the 3.2 kernel and later, and the author has no intention of supporting the 3.1.9+ due to gaping security holes ([Chris Boot discusses the driver](http://www.bootc.net/archives/2012/06/12/why-i-wont-support-a-3-1-kernel/))
4. With luck, the Debian "wheezy" distribution, currently in beta for the RasPi, will have this driver on it.  It comes with the 3.2 kernel.

Comment: Yes, as you mention it is built into the standard kernel now - both official Raspbian and Debian wheezy distros. I followed some advice here which is easy to follow and I have the I2C devices showing up in /dev ... http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=37&t=15511  There's a bit more detail here if required: http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/files/rpi_i2c_setup.doc

Comment: To get more detailed, keep data here rather than on weblinks, and hoping this doesn't get out of date: As of the Wheezy 2012-09-18 image, you edit `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` and comment out the entry for `i2c-bcm2708`; then edit `/etc/modules` and append `i2c-dev`; then reboot. You should now have a `/dev/i2c-0` special file, which is very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some examples I've done

- [Measuring Temperature](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1216/590)
- [Analog to digital converter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1326/590)
- [Generating signals](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1435/590)

Answer (score 2):

**Hardware:**

As mentioned by Tapio, the hardware is well documented at http://elinux.org/Rpi_Low-level_peripherals

**Software:**

There is a i2c-dev header in the Linux userspace (`#include <linux/i2c-dev.h>`). Furthermore you need a character decive to read from. This can be done by loading the correct modules. `i2c_bcm2708` for the low level driver and `i2c-dev` for generating the character decives for the busses. Apply ...

```
sudo modprobe -r i2c_bcm2708
sudo modprobe i2c_bcm2708 baudrate=<your preferred baudrate>
```

for loading them on the fly. Apply ...

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "i2c-dev" >> /etc/modules'
sudo sh -c 'echo "options i2c_bcm2708 baudrate=<your preferred baudrate>\n" > /etc/modprobe.d/custom.conf
```

and unblacklist `i2c_bcm2708` in `/etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf` to make `/dev/i2c-0` and `/dev/i2c-1` show up permanently.

From now on you can follow the [hints on how to use I²C](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface) del maestro himself.

I prefer this method over others, because it is platformagnostic. Your can use `linux/i2c-dev.h` with other devices too, as long as there exists a low level I²C driver.

Regards