# What is a accurate way to generate and decode IR signals?

Tags: hardware, signal

I want to receive and generate IR signals with my PI.  What is the best way to reliably do this?  Would it be with something like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-generate-frequency-pulse-signals)?

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/). I bought a cheap IR sensor (Philips OVU412000) from ebay and set up LIRC to receive signals from a TV remote in order to control a program I wrote. Works great on my Pi. I haven't looked into generating signals, but I think LIRC is capable of this.

[image]

Comment: How did you interface the IR sensor to the PI?  RS232 or USB?  Can you post the specifics?  Thanks!

Comment: The IR receiver is USB and it's connected to the Pi via a USB hub (powered, as I have other stuff connected also.) Do you need any other info?

Comment: Can you provide details of how you interfaced the IR sensor to USB?  Also part number would be great too!  Thanks

Comment: The receiver is a Philips OVU412000. You don't need to do any interfacing as it's all handled by LIRC/kernel stuff; just plug and go.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [project](http://aron.ws/projects/lirc_rpi/) on how to use [LIRC](http://www.lirc.org/) to interface the PI to a home made receiver and transmitter.  There is also a third schematic for a transceiver.

The receiver looks to be pretty simple, just a TSOP1238 directly connected to GPIO pins 1, 6 & 12 on the Pi.

Comment: I defininetly could be wrong, but I don't think the PI has the ability to **accurately** generate or decode the 38k signals.

Comment: @shaun5 It should be ok given it is implemented as a kernel module.