# Simple intercom with rPi

Tags: audio, rpi.gpio

I saw someone had a question a couple of years ago about connecting his intercom (which used a phone line) to a rPi and none of the answers were realistic. I also would like to do some simple project but without using too much additional hardware (eg, no readymade landline intercom) which transmits in a way that is readily available and cheap. I was thinking of having some simple FM circuit connect to the GPIO and transmit that way, with packet audio.

I am not new to rPi and have skills with soldering and basic electronics and think this would be a great project for short range (and legal) telecoms between two rPi Zero W's.

I realise also that using external FM transceivers could be extraneous and perhaps its possible to do it via built-in WiFi, saving time and money. It would require a mic and speaker thought but they are so cheap.

Any inquiring minds welcome to comment or criticise! I did do a decent search for this idea and didn't find anything that was what I was thinking about...as I mentioned earlier someone mentioned using Asterix which IMO is overkill, given the simple task required. I couldnt reply on that original query as I am new here and don't have 50 points.

PS posting a simple question on this site is difficult to do when you are new :(

Comment: I'm surprised you only seem to refer to one question a couple of years ago and allegedly only asterisk was suggested - searching the phrase "raspberry pi intercom" results in many such projects, and not one I've looked at even hints at asterisk

Comment: "allegedly" like I committed a crime. Lovely response! Original question not posted because I assumed I couldn't post URL's. Not sure why my simple question made you confrontational though. Perhaps this community isn't for me. here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13800/raspberry-pi-as-intercom

Comment: *allege: to assert without proof* - you posted no link in your question - therefore, no proof - please, don't infer I was accusing you of something sinister, perhaps my use of the English language is inelegant compared to you, for which I humbly prostrate myself before you and beg for forgiveness

Comment: Perhaps something could be cobbled together using `netcat`? Have a look  [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/send-audio-over-network-888169/#post4857780).

Comment: Interesting. I am wanting to do this so my elderly neighbour could have a simple PTT type intercom. If netcat can be used to send a beep or mp3 then initiate a live audio stream that would be perfect! Thanks Roger

Comment: this seems to be the best solution I think: http://projectable.me/i-built-a-wifi-walkie-talkie-for-my-kids-now-you-can-too/

Comment: Hi @user129949 Really welcome to the site :-). You wrote "*posting a simple question on this site is difficult to do when you are new*". It would become easy if you take the very short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: Also, if you ever need to post a link that refers to another question or answer either on a SE site or elsewhere you can get a good link to use by clicking on the *share* option underneath the body of that question or answer.  As it happens, Big Brother (or is it [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)?) does also note your id within that link and watches how it is used to work out your progress towards the Announcer badge (check out "Other badges" [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges))!