# Connecting a standard telephone through GPIO

Tags: gpio, electronics

I am wondering if you can interface a standard, RJ11 telephone through GPIO, and input an output through the phone, even using asterisk to connect to voip. The phone I have is a GE model number 29255ge2 which I believe was made around the late 1990s and early 2000s. I am wondering if you can remove the RJ connector from one end, somehow connect the red and green wire to gpio. One concern I have is that 5 volts will be enough to power the phone, and also making it ring, I know normal ringing voltage is 60v AC I believe.

BTW I am not connecting this to the phone line, also basically if you are misunderstanding this I am basically trying to use the pi as cheapo Analog Telephone Adapter.

Comment: The Pi's GPIO are 3V3 and can drive perhaps 20 mA.  What signals do you plan to send down the phone line?  Would connecting non-approved kit to the phone line be legal in your jurisdiction?

Comment: Not to mention what is on the other end some phone lines send a very high voltage for the ring - which would instantly fry your Pi. What is the actuial goal? beyond connecting a phone to the Pi.

Comment: I am not connecting anything to the phone line, I am connecting a phone to the pi, and basically I want to be able to make calls from it, its kind of a "because I can" thing and I don't care abount incoming ring that much. In fact, one of the reasons is because I don't even have a landline.

Answer (score 4):

So from what I understand you're trying to make the RPi into an ATA device. Some combination of GPIO pins are wired into a phone cable that plugs into a analogue phone handset.

Could be possible in a run-around way, with a DAC/amp circuit in-between, you could use I2C for audio i/o see [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/702/how-can-i-use-i2c-to-talk-to-sensors) for more info.

A couple of other options might save some hair pulling:

1. Get a USB to FXS device [like this](http://amfeltec.com/products/piranha-usb-fxs-adapter/) - the one I linked has Linux drivers, so some possibility of an easy-ish job, then combine with something like RasPBX running on the RPi.
2. Ditch the idea of using the RPi and just buy a cheap or used [Cisco ATA](http://search.ebay.com/cisco-ata) and plug that into your analogue phone handset.

Personally I'd go with the second option and save myself about 50 hours.