# Convert PSTN to VoIP using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: networking

**Problem**

I'm currently working on a project based on raspberry pi. I have a PSTN line input to Raspberry Pi and I want to convert incoming analog call to VoIP. Then using a softphone application receive that call on mobile application.

**What I want**

I want to convert PSTN call to VoIP in real time using Raspberry Pi and after converting or before convering access information like Caller ID. So is there anyway I can accomplish that using raspberry pi without using external device?

I don't know much about telecommunication. So thought to put the question here. Thanks.

Comment: "I have a PSTN line input to Raspberry Pi" **How??** the Pi has no PSTN input. There are packages to configure the Pi (or other systems) as a VOIP PABX e.g. Asterix, but setting these up is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Related links [connecting-a-standard-telephone-through-gpio](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36986/connecting-a-standard-telephone-through-gpio) or  [Free Home Phone with Raspberry Pi](http://www.littlebytesofpi.com/raspberrypihomephone/) or [google yourself](http://www.google.com/search?q=raspberry+pi+analog+telephone+adapter) @Milliways Nitpicking: it's Asterisk